# How to re-boot windows 7 pc after uninstalling Ca anti virus Applications

Tags: windows-7, windows

I un installed Ca anti virus and when i tried to install Kaspersky antivirus, it still says i have one (Ca Etrust suite Personal) application, which i need to uninstall, but after searching entire PC, i could not find this apps on my PC. But the Kaspersky was unable to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [CA antivirus removal tool](http://homeofficekb.ca.com/CIDocument.asp?KDId=3125&Preview=0&Return=0&GUID=DF325E0AA0AB4264AF47E4BEA49F571B) to uninstall it, reboot the machine and try installing Kaspersky again.